# Hibernate filter with if condition

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    @Filter(name = "localeFilter", condition = "locale= :localeFilterParam")
    private Set<PersonLocale> personLocales;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person_locale")
public class Person {

    private Long id;        
    private String name;
    private String locale;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("person_id")
    private Person person;
}

sample data:

Person
id  
1

PersonLocale
id  person_id   locale  name
1   1           en      John
2   1           fr      Jean
```

My application have a default language, eg: '`en`'
Data for the default language is mandatory while others are optional.

When I query the person details.
I use Hibernate filter to filter the locale I want.
It is working fine if I have the data for the locale I set into `localeFilterParam`.
However, when I pass in a locale with no record in database such as '`de`'.
The `personLocales` will be null.

Does hibernaate have a feature like
- check whether the filter has record
- if dont have, it will query the `personLocale` again with the default language `en`

I know that there are `CASE` statement in native SQL. How can I do that in hibernate?

Edit:

I am planning not to filter the locale, instead load all the locale.
Then, programmatically get the locale I want, if the locale data is null, I still can get the default language.

Is this design not efficient or bad?

When the number of locale increase, it may load many unneeded locale data

Edit:
found that HQL supports case when statement but only for where not select